# Alignment of terms horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to replicate this look from a textbook, where the terms are aligned horizontally, but how do I keep the alignment when I want to exclude a particular term, as pictured?  Do I use the `align` environment, or is there another method?

[image: inequalities alignment]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional way is with `amsmath` environments, but here it is with a TABstack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[
\TABbinary
\tabularLongstack{rrl}
{
2x_1 & + x_2 & \le 100\\
x_1  & + x_2 & \le 80\\
x_1  &       & \le 40\\
x_1  &       & \ge 0\\
     &   x_2 & \ge 0
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer a follow up from the OP, there are several ways to add a comment off to the right of the stacked equations, using the TABstack approach.  Here, I show 2 ways, with the comments added as a separate `\Longstack`, and then as part of the original `\tabularLongstack`. Either one works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMath
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
Comments as part of separate stack
\[
\TABbinaryLeft
\tabularLongstack{rrl}
{
2x_1 & + x_2 & \le 100\\
x_1  & + x_2 & \le 80\\
x_1  &       & \le 40\\
x_1  &       & \ge 0\\
     &   x_2 & \ge 0
}\qquad
\Longstack[l]{
Comment 1\\
Comment 2\\
Comment 3\\
Comment 4\\
Comment 5
}
\]
As a single tabularstack
\[
\TABbinaryLeft
\tabularLongstack{rrll}
{
2x_1 & + x_2 & \le 100 &\qquad\text{Comment 1}\\
x_1  & + x_2 & \le 80  &\qquad\text{Comment 2}\\
x_1  &       & \le 40  &\qquad\text{Comment 3}\\
x_1  &       & \ge 0   &\qquad\text{Comment 4}\\
     &   x_2 & \ge 0   &\qquad\text{Comment 5}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, @Steven-B-Segletes!  I've never heard of nor seen that package before.  Is there a way to include a comment to the right of each line?

Comment: @jbrow35 If you don't mind specifying them in a separate stack, then `\[
\TABbinaryLeft
\tabularLongstack{rrl}
{
2x_1 & + x_2 & \le 100\\
x_1  & + x_2 & \le 80\\
x_1  &       & \le 40\\
x_1  &       & \ge 0\\
     &   x_2 & \ge 0
}\qquad
\Longstack{
Comment 1\\
Comment 2\\
Comment 3\\
Comment 4\\
Comment 5
}
\]`

Comment: @jbrow35 If you want it as a single tabular stack, then add `amsmath` package and this: `\[
\TABbinaryLeft
\tabularLongstack{rrll}
{
2x_1 & + x_2 & \le 100 &\qquad\text{Comment 1}\\
x_1  & + x_2 & \le 80  &\qquad\text{Comment 2}\\
x_1  &       & \le 40  &\qquad\text{Comment 3}\\
x_1  &       & \ge 0   &\qquad\text{Comment 4}\\
     &   x_2 & \ge 0   &\qquad\text{Comment 5}
}
\]`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest of all here is probably the `systeme` package: no `&`, just a comma-separated list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}%

\begin{document}

\[ \systeme{ 2x_1 + x_2 \leq 100,
x_1 + x_2 \leq 80,
x_1 \leq 40,
x_1 \geq 0} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the brace, add `\sysdelim{.}{.}`. You also can add comments (more generally a second part), introduced by `@` :

```
\[ \sysdelim{.}{.}
 \systeme{ 2x_1 + x_2 \leq 100@\text{Isn't it a fine system?},
 x_1 + x_2 \leq 80,
x_1 \leq 40,
x_1 \geq 0} \]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Very judicious. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: This was a really helpful solution, thanks @Bernard!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses only the `array` package. The `array` environment is set up to let you provide comments to the right of any of the inequalities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional -- in case you need "Times Roman" look
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % column type for binary and relational operators
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{2}{rC} r @{\hspace{2cm}} >{$}l<{$} }
2x_1 & + & x_2 & \le & 100 & various restrictions on $x_1$ and $x_2$\\
 x_1 & + & x_2 & \le &  80 \\
 x_1 &   &     & \le &  40 \\
 x_1 &   &     & \ge &   0 & non-negativity restrictions\\
     &   & x_2 & \ge &   0
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```